# Can you shed more light on this conditional? If the work wasn't done already I'd have to do it when I come in tomorrow

Tags: conditionals

> If the work wasn't done already I'd have to do it when I come in tomorrow.

This conditional starts with present phenomenon and then shows a future consequence.
It is not a second conditional because we don't have "weren't" instead of "wasn't".

Question 1: how is it different from making the entire sentence 2nd conditional? -- doing so would also convey the finished character of "the work"  due to the "already".
Any thoughts on the nature of this mixed conditional are welcome.

Comment: _Please_ tell us where you found this sentence. It is poor English, for the reason you give. I would expect "If the work hasn't been done already, I'll have to do it..."

Comment: The sentence comes from here: https://www.eltconcourse.com/training/inservice/phrases_clauses_sentences/condition_concession.html

Comment: Ah - now I understand the intended meaning! (The work has in fact been done.) I was confused because, if I meant to express that idea, I would say "If the work hadn't been done already...". I would also say "when I came in tomorrow", as gotube suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is good, if not the standard way of phrasing the idea, and it's hard to parse.

You're showing a couple misconceptions, and clearing them up should allow you understand that conditional.

First, you *can* use "was" instead of "were" in an unreal clause. It's less common, but it's acceptable. With "would" later on in the sentence, it's clearly an unreal conditional. It's certainly better to use "were" because it makes it unambiguous from the start what the meaning is, but it's not required. In fact, the only time I tell students they should always use "were" is in the expression, "*If I were you...*" when giving advice, and even that expression is sometimes used with "was" by native speakers in certain varieties of English.

Second, there's nothing special about the consequence clause referring to different times. We see it even in standard classroom examples of "second conditionals":

> If I had a million dollars, I'd buy you a house.
> If I didn't have an appointment this evening already, I'd take you to dinner.

Here, "had" and "didn't have" are in the present *time*, and "would buy" and "would take" are in the future *time*. We could add a time expression like "this evening" to the end to make it absolutely clear, but even without it, those consequence clauses are in the future.

Beyond that, the main verb of the consequence clause is "have to", not "do". "Have to" refers to the present because it means *to have an obligation now*.

Third, you didn't mention this issue, but "come" is in a present tense, where you might expect it to be in the past, since it's part of an unreal conditional. This too is fine because the phrase "when I come in tomorrow" is a time expression about the *real* future, just like "this evening", but it happens to use a clause with a conjugated verb. The action of "come in" is real, not unreal, so there's no contradiction with the present tense. It would also be natural, to backshift to "came", but "come" makes it clear you are coming.

So in sum, the sentence you found is correct and exactly equivalent to this one in function and meaning:

> If the work **weren't** done already I'd have to do it when I **came** in tomorrow.